# Linux Bash Script Variable as command

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I have to create a script on RHEL and was wondering if I am able to save the output of a command as a variable. For example:

4.2.2 Ensure logging is configured (Not Scored) : = OUTPUT (which comes from the command `sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.conf`)

This is what I have now.

```
echo " ### 4.2.2 Ensure logging is configured (Not Scored) : ### "
echo " "
echo "Running command: "
echo "#sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.conf"
echo " "

sudo cat /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Thank you!

Comment: @user14135159 : Please clarify: Do you mean the **standard output** of a comand, or **stdout+stderr**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
MESSAGE=$(echo "Hello!")
echo $MESSAGE
Hello!
```

Or the old standard:

```
MESSAGE=`echo "Hello!"`
echo $MESSAGE
Hello!
```

In your case:

```
FILE_CONTENT=$(cat /etc/rsyslog.conf)
```

NOTE!!!: It is very important to not use spaces near equal!

This form is incorrect:

```
MESSAGE = `echo "Hello!"`
MESSAGE: command not found
```

Comment: It is good to explain that what you are doing (and what the OP is looking for) is called *Command Substitution*. Where the output of a command is substituted in place of the command for assignment to a variable. (I know you know but the OP may not -- always helps if they want to search further). Good note that `$(...)` is preferred over the older `\`...\``.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: `echo $MESSAGE` is buggy. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 2):

```
variable=$(command)
variable=$(command [option…] argument1 arguments2 …)
variable=$(/path/to/command)
```

Taken from https://linuxhint.com/bash_command_output_variable/

Comment: `command` is the name of a specific command built into the shell. It should not be used as a standin for other commands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What does command do? Simple executing?

Comment: By default, it forces an external command to be used instead of an alias or function for a single execution. Add the `-v` option and it behaves like a built-in version of `which`.